# Constraint's constant remains same but Label changes its position

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ios-autolayout

I am designing a UITableViewCell which has 2 image and 1 label. I am using Xcode 9.2 and designed cell using Autolayout.

The weird thing that I am facing is:  when I try to test the UI design for different screen sizes by tapping on devices listed at the bottom of Xcode, the UILabel on right side changes its position. But the trailing constraint's value remains same.

I am posting screenshots from Xcode for better understanding

**Screenshot for iPhone X:**

[image]

**Screenshot for iPhone SE:**

[image]

**Screenshot for iPhone 8 plus:**

[image]

As you can see in screenshots attached that Constant for trailing constraint is same button imageView has changed its position for different screen sizes.

I have tried creating new storyboard, new ViewController, new everything but issue is same. Also, I noticed that issue is with TableView only. Because I tried to create a new viewController and added 3 labels on it with same constraints of UITableViewCell. Labels didn't change their position for different iPhones.

I tried to google this issue but seems like no-one faced this issue.

If anyone has any suggestion on this problem, please answer here. Any help would be appreciated.

***UPDATE:***
Here is the screenshot from device:

[image]

Comment: No, I had to create similar design in separate project and then added that into existing project.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error but a storyboard layout rendering issue. An interface builder changes its size, when ever you switches between different devices (from `View as` panel).

In case of `UITableViewCell` it does not changes its size (width) according to device size (width).

**An answer to your question**: You need to update/reset `UITableViewCell` size according to interface builder size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Krunal. I tried to test the same on device, the issue is same. Label changes it's width according to its content.

Comment: Did you set predefined text in it? Yea, I saw that your constraint showing an updated size that is the reason for extra content size.

Comment: I have update the question with new  screenshot taken from device. The text on label is changing on run time. Here, the dummy text is set in cellForRowAtIndexPath method for testing.

Comment: Okay. I will create a dummy one.

Comment: please download sample project from this link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmp56tfj8vr49ma/TableViewCellIssue.zip?dl=0

Comment: @SushilSharma - after adding tableview and cell code to your project, it displays fine: https://imgur.com/a/Pn3Gn ... When you switch "View As:" device, select one of your image views, tap left-arrow-key to move it 1-pt to the left, then tap right-arrow-key to move it back. The label and the other image view should automatically re-position themselves. It does appear to be a new IB bug (I just updated to Xcode 9.3, and I don't remember seeing this behavior in the past).

Comment: @SushilSharma - it shouldn't matter... as I said, when I run your TableViewCellIssue app, the layout works fine, and in IB / Storyboard, you can get the cell to update as I described.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks, Yes sample project works well on all devices.But main project still has the issue. I will to check with the main project. Seems like I have checked/unchecked some property in tableView or storyboard.